# Turn on/off or adjust Slow Keys on OS X with commandline script

Tags: macos, applescript

I have RSI and part of my managment is reducing key presses per hour to less than 3,000. I am using WhatPulse to track this number, and TextBar to display it to me:

[image]

I have a cronjob each minute that runs `say 'Slow down'` if I exceed 3k. I find that I exceed it a lot. I've used Slow Keys in the past:

[image]

Which basically limits your typing speed. I'd like to activate/adjust it when I reach the 2k/h rate.

How do I do that programmatically? Perhaps AppleScript?

Comment: My answer, as presently coded, makes the change without the System Preferences UI showing, however if you want to set the value of the 'Acceptance Delay:' or check/uncheck the 'Use click key sounds' checkbox with 'Slow Keys' options, the UI has to be visible, because it's on a sheet, not a regular window. Do you need the _code_ to make those changes as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* toggles the state of the **Enable Slow Keys** check box:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    if running then quit
    delay 0.5
    reveal anchor "Keyboard" of pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
    tell application "System Events"
        click checkbox "Enable Slow Keys" of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

**Notes:**

- As this *script* uses **UI Scripting**, when run from **Script Editor**, the app must be added to **System Preferences** > **Security** & **Privacy** > **Accessibility** in order to *run* properly. Saved as an *application*, the saved application would need to be added.
- Also with **UI Scripting**, the value of the `delay` *command* may need to be changed for use on your system (and or additional `delay` *commands* added as appropriate, although in the case additional `delay` *commands* should not be needed).

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* was tested on macOS 10.12.6. It should also work of several previous major versions, however in OS X 10.8 the following needs to be used:

```
click checkbox "Enable Slow Keys" of group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"
```

Comment: I've noticed that it's not entirely reliable due to the timing issue and needing to be visible on the screen. Is this the best we can achieve with AppleScript? Is there not a way to do it with e.g. `defaults`?

Comment: @Christopher Done, For this particular change, the UI does not need to be visible and as already noted the _value_ of the `delay` _command_ may need to be changed for your system. On my system this works without issues as coded, adjust the _value_ of the `delay` _command_ as appropriate for your system. If you need additional `delay` _commands_ do so as necessary. Since OS X 10.8 the use of the `defaults` _command_ to make changes to most System Preferences no longer take immediate effect and are often overwritten before that can take effect. This is why UI Scripting is being used here.

Comment: @Christopher Done, The settings the `defaults` _command_ can change and take effect then need to have the target process restarted and while this can be easily done with Finder and or the Dock, it's not doable here. Additionally restarting Finder and or the Dock is messy in that it disrupts the UI more so then UI Scripting does.  You'd probably need to use Objective-C or Cocoa-AppleScript to make changes immediately without UI Scripting where using `defaults` is no longer the option it used to be.